# Refactor If/Else Statements

Tags: php

I'm trying to find a better way to write this logic.  Using the PHP class FDF, I'm checking the value of checkboxes from from and adding an image to the coordinate in a PDF.

```
        if ($salutation[0] == "Dr.") {

            $pdf->Image('/inc/checked.png',31.4, 105.5,-300);
            $pdf->Image('/inc/unchecked.png',43.5, 105.5,-300);
            $pdf->Image('/inc/unchecked.png',56, 105.5,-300);
            $pdf->Image('/inc/unchecked.png',70.5, 105.5,-300);

        }elseif ($salutation[0] == "Mr.") {

            $pdf->Image('/inc/checked.png',43.5, 105.5,-300);
            $pdf->Image('/inc/unchecked.png',31.4, 105.5,-300);
            $pdf->Image('/inc/unchecked.png',56, 105.5,-300);
            $pdf->Image('/inc/unchecked.png',70.5, 105.5,-300);

        }elseif ($salutation[0] == "Mrs.") {

            $pdf->Image('/inc/checked.png',56, 105.5,-300);
            $pdf->Image('/inc/unchecked.png',31.4, 105.5,-300);
            $pdf->Image('/inc/unchecked.png',43.5, 105.5,-300);
            $pdf->Image('/inc/unchecked.png',70.5, 105.5,-300);

        }elseif ($salutation[0] == "Ms.") {

            $pdf->Image('/inc/checked.png',70.5, 105.5,-300);
            $pdf->Image('/inc/unchecked.png',31.4, 105.5,-300);
            $pdf->Image('/inc/unchecked.png',43.5, 105.5,-300);
            $pdf->Image('/inc/unchecked.png',56, 105.5,-300);
        }
```

A switch statement seems like pretty much the same thing.  The problem for me is that in any case, the other images still need to be added.  Is there a better way to do this?

Comment: The `switch` statement would fit this batter

Comment: Why not just use a loop?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The easiest option of all is to use ternary operators. Do not overcomplicate this simple issue by using fancy arrays, functions or loops. So you could just replace that whole thing with 4 lines of code:

```
$pdf->Image('/inc/' . (($salutation[0] == 'Dr.') ? '' : 'un') . 'checked.png',31.4, 105.5,-300);
$pdf->Image('/inc/' . (($salutation[0] == 'Mr.') ? '' : 'un') . 'checked.png',43.5, 105.5,-300);
$pdf->Image('/inc/' . (($salutation[0] == 'Mrs.') ? '' : 'un') . 'checked.png',56, 105.5,-300);
$pdf->Image('/inc/' . (($salutation[0] == 'Ms.') ? '' : 'un') . 'checked.png',70.5, 105.5,-300);
```

You are welcome. :)

Comment: Indeed. I love good loops as well, but I love well placed ternary operators even more. :)

Answer (score 2):

How about

```
$coords = array(
    'Dr.' => array(31.4, 105.5,-300),
    'Mr.' => array(43.5, 105.5,-300),
    'Mrs.' => array(56, 105.5,-300),
    'Ms.' => array(70.5, 105.5,-300)
);

foreach ($coords as $title => $coord) {
    if($salutation[0] == $title) {
        $pdf->Image('/inc/checked.png', $coord[0], $coord[1], $coord[2]);
    } else {
        $pdf->Image('/inc/unchecked.png', $coord[0], $coord[1], $coord[2]);
    }
}
```

Comment: The first line inside the array is missing a comma.

Answer (score 0):

Try a switch

```
switch($salutation[0]){
    case 'Dr.':
        //do stuff
    break;

    case 'Mr.':
        //do stuff
    break;

    case 'Mrs.':
        //do stuff
    break;
}
```

Comment: I would still need to add 4 images per case though.

Answer (score 0):

You could simplify your creation of the images and reduce repeated code by using a simple function that takes 4 numbers:

```
function handleImages($a, $b, $c, $d) {
    $pdf->Image('/inc/checked.png', $a, 105.5, -300);
    $pdf->Image('/inc/unchecked.png', $b, 105.5, -300);
    $pdf->Image('/inc/unchecked.png', $c, 105.5, -300);
    $pdf->Image('/inc/unchecked.png', $d, 105.5, -300);
}
```

You could then call your function within a simplified switch:

```
switch($salutation[0]){
    case 'Dr.':
        handleImages(31.4, 43.5, 56, 70.5);
        break;
    case 'Mr.':
        handleImages(43.5, 31.4, 56, 70.5);
        break;
    case 'Mrs.':
        handleImages(56, 43.5, 31.4, 70.5);
        break;
    case 'Ms.':
        handleImages(70.5, 56, 43.5, 31.4);
        break;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Since this is PHP - it would make our work a lot simple!! You can use associative arrays.

There is indeed a better way of doing the following - but I like the simplicity of the following piece of code:

```
$checkedPos = array ("Dr." => 31.4, "Mr." => 43.5, "Mrs." => 56, "Ms." => 70.5);
$unchecked1Pos = array ("Dr." => 43.5, "Mr." => 56, "Mrs." => 70.5, "Ms." => 31.4);
$unchecked2Pos = array ("Dr." => 56, "Mr." => 70.5, "Mrs." => 31.4, "Ms." => 43.5);
$unchecked3Pos = array ("Dr." => 70.5, "Mr." => 31.4, "Mrs." => 43.5, "Ms." => 56);

$pdf->Image('/inc/checked.png', $checkedPos[$salutation[0]], 105.5, -300);
$pdf->Image('/inc/unchecked.png', $unchecked1Pos[$salutation[0]], 105.5, -300);
$pdf->Image('/inc/unchecked.png', $unchecked2Pos[$salutation[0]], 105.5, -300);
$pdf->Image('/inc/unchecked.png', $unchecked3Pos[$salutation[0]], 105.5, -300);
```

Hope that helps.